# MySQL InnoDB SELECT...LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE Vs UPDATE ... LIMIT 1

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table v_ext in a MySQL with InnoDB engine:
 - id: primary key
 - code: pre-generated list of codes (say 1000 codes are generated randomly)
 - user_id: initially NULL

When a user purchase an item, they receive a code. I need to update the table to populate the user_id column. I have two options:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT id FROM v_ext WHERE user_id IS NULL LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE; -- return id 54 for ex.
UPDATE v_ext SET user_id=xxx WHERE id=54;
COMMIT;
```

or

```
UPDATE v_ext SET user_id=xxx WHERE user_id IS NULL LIMIT 1;
```

Is the second option safe if I have thousands of users purchasing at the same time? If so, is it correct to assume this second option is better for performance since it needs only one query?

Comment: Is there a `UNIQUE` constraint on `user_id`?  (i.e. can a user only have one code)?

Comment: `EXISTS` would be a better use in terms of concurrency and performance.

Comment: UNIQUE is not a constraint, a user_id can get as many code as they purchase item

Comment: @bonCodigo could you elaborate? Do mean something like `UPDATE v_ext SET user_id=xxx WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM v_ext WHERE user_id IS NULL LIMIT 1)` ?

Comment: @JScoobyCed `UPDATE v_ext SET user_id=xxx WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM v_ext WHERE ID = 54 AND user_id IS NULL)` but I believe more seasoned experts here could provide you with a better answer to compare which would be best in your case :) +1 for the interesting question focusing on performance.

Comment: @bonCodigo thanks. But I need to query to get the 54 id so it's 2 queries this way, and concurrency issues would raise. I'll try this route anyway when i get back to my office

Comment: @JScoobyCed Send `ID` as a variable in that case. Eager to know the outcome of this question.

Comment: @bonCodigo Trying both your and my SQL using the EXISTS result in error 1093 `You can't specify target table  for update in FROM clause`. I am going to benchmark my two options and post the results

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since I didn't get an answer, I started doing benchmarking. My criteria are as follows:

- 20,000 pre-generated codes
- Use of Apache `ab` command with 20,000 requests, 100 concurrency: `ab -n 20000 -c 100`
- Servlet -> EJB (JPA 2.0 EclipseLink, JTA) to perform the update in DB (as it will be through a JSF action in real situation)
- 2 versions of the Servlet, one with option 1 (SELECT ... FOR UPDATE ), and one with option 2 (UPDATE ... LIMIT 1)
- Stopped Glassfish, hit the tested Servlet manually 5 times to warm it up, reset all to NULL to user_id
- Tests are run 3 times each and average is provided

Results:

SELECT ... FOR UPDATE; UPDATE ... :

```
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   758.116 seconds
Complete requests:      20000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Row updated:            20000
```

UPDATE.... LIMIT 1:

```
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   773.659 seconds
Complete requests:      20000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Row updated:            20000
```

So at least on my system, the option with 2 queries seems more efficient than the one query. I didn't expect that :)

Comment: +1 Interesting findings. Did it cause any concurrency issues?

Comment: Not that I can see. I updated 20,000 rows through 20,000 successful requests.

Comment: Follow up question with deadlock occurring only when I index user_id actually a varchar column) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052038/mysql-select-for-update-with-index-has-concurrency-issue